# Can't deploy to Scrapy cloud, problem with importing even common modules

Tags: python, scrapy

I am attempting to deploy a spider to Scrapy cloud, but I am repeatedly running into requirements problems, even importing commonly used modules such as io, re, shlex and PyPDF2. I am using Python 3.5. My `scrapinghub.yml` file contains these lines:

```
projects:
    default: 358310
stacks:
    default: scrapy:1.3-py3
requirements:
    file: requirements.txt
```

My `requirements.txt` file contains these lines:

```
io
re
shlex
PyPDF2==1.26.0
```

This is the error I got:

```
Login succeeded
Building an image:
Step 1/12 : FROM scrapinghub/scrapinghub-stack-scrapy:1.3-py3
[91m# Executing 2 build triggers...
[0m
Step 1/1 : ENV PIP_TRUSTED_HOST $PIP_TRUSTED_HOST PIP_INDEX_URL $PIP_INDEX_URL
 ---> Using cache
Step 1/1 : RUN test -n $APT_PROXY && echo 'Acquire::http::Proxy \"$APT_PROXY\";'     >/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8d2af0ecc1ce
Step 2/12 : ENV PYTHONUSERBASE /app/python
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c5bc537289c7
Step 3/12 : ADD eggbased-entrypoint /usr/local/sbin/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 210ce92ef42e
Step 4/12 : ADD run-pipcheck /usr/local/bin/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2d0a46143fa4
Step 5/12 : RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run-pipcheck
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a2eefa41c642
Step 6/12 : RUN chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/eggbased-entrypoint &&     ln -sf /usr/local/sbin/eggbased-entrypoint /usr/local/sbin/start-crawl &&     ln -sf /usr/local/sbin/eggbased-entrypoint /usr/local/sbin/scrapy-list &&     ln -sf /usr/local/sbin/eggbased-entrypoint /usr/local/sbin/shub-image-info &&     ln -sf /usr/local/sbin/eggbased-entrypoint /usr/local/sbin/run-pipcheck
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f3f5b5c713e3
Step 7/12 : ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e6417a1c3fea
Step 8/12 : RUN mkdir /app/python && chown nobody:nogroup /app/python
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6720be2ef393
Step 9/12 : RUN sudo -u nobody -E PYTHONUSERBASE=$PYTHONUSERBASE     pip install --user --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 8d8694511a74
Collecting io (from -r /app/requirements.txt (line 1))
[91m  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement io (from -r /app/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
[0m
[91mNo matching distribution found for io (from -r /app/requirements.txt (line 1))
[0m
[91mYou are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
[0m
{"message": "The command '/bin/sh -c sudo -u nobody -E PYTHONUSERBASE=$PYTHONUSERBASE     pip install --user --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1", "details": {"message": "The command '/bin/sh -c sudo -u nobody -E PYTHONUSERBASE=$PYTHONUSERBASE     pip install --user --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1", "code": 1}, "error": "requirements_error"}
```

Where am I going wrong? BTW, I have the latest version of pip installed (contrary to what the error message states).

Comment: where did you find the run-pipcheck file?

Answer (score 0):

io, re, shlex are internal libraries, not packages, as I know. They should not be in requirements file.

Comment: But what about PyPDF2? I am pretty sure it's not an internal library, but is not being imported into the Scrapy project...

Comment: It is separate library: https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/ So it should be installed as you wrote in requirements.txt.